# how to import csv/data in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hy, I know many questions has been asked on it already but this is somewhat different. 
I have csv file containing millions of records. I tried the following commands to copy from csv to my table i.e.

```
copy "client_data" from '/home/mike/Desktop/client_data.txt' with delimiter ',' CSV;
```

BUT the problem arrises as the data in the csv is inconsistent state i.e.

following lines would like charm

```
12/12/12 20:17:35,304000000,"123","1"
12/12/12 20:17:36,311000000,"123","2"
12/12/12 20:17:36,814000000,"123","2"
12/12/12 20:17:36,814000000,"123","2"
12/12/12 20:17:37,317000000,"123",".1"
12/12/12 20:17:38,863000000,"123","TS"
12/12/12 20:17:39,835000000,"123","2"
12/12/12 20:17:40,337000000,"123","1"
```

but hundreds of rows are some what like

```
12/12/12 20:20:03,790000000,"123","1
{'""}__{""'}        /""'\
(      $AMZA./)@FRIDI
{__}""'{__}     /)      (\. ,,DON,,"



12/12/12 20:20:30,501000000,"123","INAM NIKALTA NHE HE KITNE SAWALO K JAWB DAY 
 /G\A\,':/\,':/S\K,':\"


12/12/12 20:22:55,928000000,"123","PAKISTAN KI BUNYAAD 
2=QUAID-E-AZAM"
12/12/12 20:22:56,431000000,"123","QUIED E AZAM
MOHAMMAD ALI JINNAH
[KFK FEROZ]"
```

which are un parseable due to line breaks, commas, invalid characters, etc.
is there any way to parse these and load the data in postgres table in efficient way?

below is the table structure

```
create table "client_data" (

date_stamp text,
points bigint,
msisdn character varying(13),
data text
)
with (OIDS = false);
alter table "client_data" owner to postgres;
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the txt in Excel, Calc or any other office tool that supports CSV? Maybe it can filter out these invalid lines, you can do some clean-ups and save it again as CSV.

Comment: I want all the data as it is in the table. first three columns have no issue, only the last column is having invalid characters. I need something that inserts fourth column data directly in database whether it have multiple commas, invalid characters, line breaks, etc.

Comment: Look up on the option `QUOTE` for postgres. It allows you to use all the text between the QUOTE-defined character (mostly `"`). If you quote all your data properly, you should be good to go.

Comment: It looks like there are unquoted newlines and quotes in the last field. That is a problem that *in general* cannot be solved. If you cannot get cleanly escaped/quoted csv, the best you could do would be IMHO to move them to a separate file (I tend to move them to the end of the file first), edit that and import it separately.

Comment: more than 14K errors are there! do you still think it should be done that way?. I have made application in java to solve such issue. will answer my question after some time. (waiting for someone to solve this first).

Comment: With 14K errors, I would build a program, too. At least to detect and filter the erroneous records.

Comment: I did it finally using mysql import option. It saved my lot of time, and gracefully imported all that ambiguous stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using MySql import option as MySql had more sophisticated and relative easy import approach for importing data.